# Remove default selected state from woocommerce checkout billing shipping fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have selected default country from admin end **United State**, but problem is that the state **Oregon** is coming as the default selected I want to leave state field not default selected so the customer can free to search and select the state

any suggest: below is the screenshot country is ok but state need empty to type for the customer

[image: https://prnt.sc/lsy6xz]

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please put this code in `functions.php` file.

```
//default checkout state
add_filter( 'default_checkout_billing_state', 'change_default_checkout_state' );
add_filter( 'default_checkout_shipping_state', 'change_default_checkout_state' );
function change_default_checkout_state() {
    return ''; //set state code if you want to set it otherwise leave it blank.
}
```

**Note:** `default_checkout_state` filter hook is now deprecated. So Please `default_checkout_billing_state` and `default_checkout_shipping_state` hooks to change default state on checkout page.

Comment: Thanks its working very fast thank you so much dear sir

Comment: I am happy to help you :)

Answer (score 3):

In WooCommerce 7.1 you can also set this in the WooCommerce `General Options` without needing to use a PHP snippet.

[image: screenshot]